# clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to install the [dominance analysis package](https://pypi.org/project/dominance-analysis/) but it is erroring out because of numpy with the following, any ideas?

Here is the entire error output https://justpaste.it/8kif7

```
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly

       note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
      
      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> numpy
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
```

Answer (score -2):

I was running into the same issue as you. What version of python are you trying to install numpy on. By switching my version from 3.7.13 to 3.9.2 it began working for me.